# Factorizing a $6$th degree polynomial with $7$ terms.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

$$f(x) = 5x^6 + 6x^5 - 48x^4 - 68x^3 + 58x^2 + 128x + 15$$

How to simplify this to $(x^3 - 8x - 1) (5x^3 + 6x^2 - 8x - 15)$?

I have no idea. Thank you.

Comment: Multiply it out and see that it works.

Comment: Right, Im trying to find out how to factor to that

Comment: Use a computer algebra system. Why would it ever be important to factor a seemingly random $6$-th degree polynomial by hand? It's doable, but most likely it just requires routine but tedious case analysis, with no great insights to be had.

Comment: So whats the algorithm that the computer is using? Why can't a human replicate that?

Comment: You can, it's not hard -- it's just tedious. And there is not just one algorithm. There are many such algorithms.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: google wiki Factorization_of_polynomials Classical_methods

Comment: Pages $241$-$283$ of the following text 

$$\text{Mignotte & Stefanescu -- Polynomials - An Algorithmic Approach (1999)}$$

decribe three different algorithms for factoring in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.